# Advice setting up redirect on direct image access

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm just looking for some advice on the best way to to redirect on direct image access

Basically all my images are stored in mysite.com/images/ and are named 1.gif 2.gif 3.gif and so on - these images can also be accessed via mysite.com/display.php?imageName=1.gif

What im looking for is the the best way to redirect when someone directly access the image at mysite.com/images/1.gif and redirects it to mysite.com/display.php?imageName=1.gif

Many Thanks

Comment: This can be done using mod_rewrite, but why do you need the PHP script in between in the first place?

Comment: Basically my images are being viewed directly and im wanting the directly viewed images to redirect to the page the images and ads are on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^images/(.+?\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ /display.php?imageName=$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply - How would this affect websites that have embedded my images

Comment: It won't cause any trouble to them but instead of hotlinked image it will show your other php image link with ads.

Comment: @anubhava: Well, if other pages are embedding them as _images_ and get served a HTML document instead, it will of course “affect them” – in that the browser will not be able to display them any more.

Comment: `/display.php` has to make sure to server correct contentType to be able to display image in the browser.